# Quick jQuery selector child elements

Tags: jquery, class, element, this

I have a set of elements like this:

```
<ol id="selectable">
    <li class="ui-state-default">A</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">B</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">C</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">D</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">E</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">F</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">G</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">H</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">I</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">J</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">K</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">L</li>
</ol>
```

This is my jquery code:

```
$(function() {
        $( "#selectable" ).click(function(){
            $(this).switchClass( "ui-state-highlight", 1000 );
            return false;   
        });
    });
```

For some reason I am having trouble understanding what I am doing wrong. I think I may be misunderstanding the meaning of 'this'. I want the switchClass only to switch the class of whichever element I clicked on.

Comment: what is it exactly that you're trying to do? Are you trying to transition between classes on the `<ul>` or the `<li>` elements? In either case, `.switchClass` requires a class name to transition TO; you're only providing the class name to transition FROM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is this

```
$(function() {
    // Use $( "#selectable > li" ) if you want to limit to direct children
    $( "#selectable li" ).click(function(){  //  binds the click event all li descendants of selectable
        $(this).switchClass("ui-state-default", "ui-state-highlight", 1000);  // this is now the li that was clicked
        return false;   
    });
});
```

better way would be to delegate as it's more efficient by not binding an event handler to each `li` but having a parent element listen for the event as it bubbles up

```
$(function() {
    $( "#selectable" ).on('click','li'(function(){  
        $(this).switchClass("ui-state-default", "ui-state-highlight", 1000);  // this is now the li that was clicked
        return false;   
    });
});
```

unless you want to click each #selectable which wouldn't be valid since ID's need to be unique.  You can change it to a class and use

```
$(function() {
    $( ".selectable" ).click(function(){  
        $(this).switchClass("ui-state-default", "ui-state-highlight", 1000);  
        return false;   
    });
});
```

You can use toggleClass like the following

```
$(function() {
    $("#selectable").on('click', 'li', function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("ui-state-default ui-state-highlight"); // this is now the li that was clicked
        return false;
    });
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/G33Mc/

Comment: This is true, but it would be much more efficient to delegate the event handler to `#selectable`.

Comment: This ignores the fact that the call to `switchClass` is flawed.

Comment: It appears what I was looking for was the 'toggleClass' call. Thanks for the help guys

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to select the children, you could go about it using any of the following methods. :)

```
$(function() {
    // this will find all immediate children inside #selectable
    $('#selectable').children().click(function() {
        $(this).switchClass('ui-state-highlight', 1000); 
    });

    // this will find all immediate children that, are an li, inside #selectable
    $('#selectable > li').click(function() {
        $(this).switchClass('ui-state-highlight', 1000); 
    });

    // alternatively, we could look for all anchors inside the li items
    $('#selectable li a').click(function() {
        $(this).switchClass('ui-state-highlight', 1000); 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears this is what you want, assuming you're trying to transition between the 'default' class and the 'highlight' class. This is a delegated event attached to the `#selectable` element which will fire whenever an `li` within it is clicked. `this` will refer to the `li` clicked.

```
$( "#selectable" ).on('click','li',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).switchClass("ui-state-default", "ui-state-highlight", 1000);
});
```